# How to draw an ellipse using HTML map?

Tags: html

I know that using the `map` tag, I would have to use the polygon shape. However, how would I specify the coordinates so that it selects an ellipse? 
Here's the image I'm working with:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: html map is not used for drawing ellipse [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap)

Comment: Is it not possible using polygon?

Comment: no these are image maps, they dont draw anything. You probably want to use html 5 canvas element for that.

Comment: Oh, I understand what I just wrote. I meant how would I use the map tag to select that ellipse, not draw an ellipse. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ellipse available in map tag. What you can use is use two circles (for the ends) and a poly at the center. All of these three image maps should point to the same link.

For using poly, you can refer to this stack over flow question
[Image map area poly certain coords Firefox doesn't work, IE works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395606/image-map-area-poly-certain-coords-firefox-doesnt-work-ie-works)

For circles, you can use this [w3school link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)